# Angularjs dynamic ng-if data binding in span

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this Angular expression in my view:

```
 <span ng-if="{{list.StoreList ? (list.StoreList.length ' Products)' : '(0 Products)'}}"> </span>
```

So if I have any items in the StoreList then I'll display the count, otherwise I'll just show 0 products.

I'm getting unexpected expecting error from Angularjs.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<span ng-if="list.StoreList">{{'(' + list.StoreList.length + ' Products)'}}</span>
<span ng-if="!list.StoreList">(0 Products)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not formatted correctly

```
<span ng-if="{{list.StoreList ? (list.StoreList.length ' Products)' : '(0 Products)'}}"> </span>
```

should probably be

```
<span ng-if="{{ list.StoreList ? '(' + list.StoreList.length + ' Products)' : '(0 Products)'}}"> </span>
```